# `go mod graph` doesn't seem to provide the full graph

Tags: go, module, dependencies

Consider the following program

```golang
package main

import (
        "github.com/spf13/viper"
        "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

func main() {
        spew.Dump(viper.New())
}
```

with the following `go.mod` file:

```
module example.com/test

go 1.22

require (
        github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1
        github.com/spf13/viper v1.18.2
)

require (
        github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.7.0 // indirect
        github.com/hashicorp/hcl v1.0.0 // indirect
        github.com/magiconair/properties v1.8.7 // indirect
        github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.5.0 // indirect
        github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2 v2.1.0 // indirect
        github.com/sagikazarmark/locafero v0.4.0 // indirect
        github.com/sagikazarmark/slog-shim v0.1.0 // indirect
        github.com/sourcegraph/conc v0.3.0 // indirect
        github.com/spf13/afero v1.11.0 // indirect
        github.com/spf13/cast v1.6.0 // indirect
        github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
        github.com/subosito/gotenv v1.6.0 // indirect
        go.uber.org/atomic v1.9.0 // indirect
        go.uber.org/multierr v1.9.0 // indirect
        golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20230905200255-921286631fa9 // indirect
        golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0 // indirect
        golang.org/x/text v0.14.0 // indirect
        gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.67.0 // indirect
        gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

Running `go mod tidy` on this `go.mod` file will actually replace `github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1` with `v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc`. I want to know what transitive dependency is (wrongly, IMO) declaring a dependency on `v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc`.

`go mod graph | grep go-spew@v1.1.2` gives

```
example.com/test github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc
github.com/spf13/viper@v1.18.2 github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc
```

From this, I can see that it's coming in via `github.com/spf13/viper@v1.18.2`, but `spf13/viper` doesn't actually have a direct dependency on `v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc`. Cloning the `spf13/viper` repo and running `go mod graph | grep go-spew@v1.1.2` gives

```
github.com/spf13/viper github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc
github.com/hashicorp/consul/api@v1.25.1 github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc
```

But it turns out `hashicorp/consul/api` doesn't have a direct dependency on `v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc` either.

I could continue this process and presumably end up finding the transitive  dependency whose `go.mod` does have a direct dependency on `v1.1.2-0.20180830191138-d8f796af33cc`, but is this how `go mod graph` is supposed to work, or am I missing something? Is there a simple way to get the full dependency graph?